# How to create a site map in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm-sitemap

Is it possible to create a new site map in Dynamics CRM? Alternatively do you have to update an existing site map to add additional navigation nodes?

Comment: Both is possible using the Sitemap Editor from the [XrmToolbox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/).

Comment: Can you provide more details? I am using the site map editor and I am not seeing and options to create a new site map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In versions before Dynamics 365 it was not possible to create a new sitemap (or have multiple sitemaps per one organization of CRM) - you would have to modify existing sitemap byt editing XML schema or using some tool like [XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com).

This is possible now in Dynamics 365. You simply create your App (Customizations -> Customize The System -> Choose Apps on the left and add New). Now, once you give your app a name, you can specify unique SiteMap (and edit it using built in SiteMap editor) for this App, entities that can be visible for this App etc. so basically you can create a separate CRM experience for Sales users and Service users, for example.